# How to disable a Linux driver

Tags: linux-kernel

using the ARM Trustzone technology, we are running a secure OS "alongside" Linux, and in our current setting, the ethernet controller is locked in the secure side, Linux can't access it (it will trigger an asynchronous external abort).
I order to prevent Linux access, I would like to disable the driver in charge of the ethernet (FEC, Freescale Ethernet Controller).
I know that I can disable the driver using "make menuconfig", but it seems a bit too radical, since we have now device-trees in Linux ARM kernel.

1. What if I remove the `fec`node of my device tree ? Will this prevent Linux access to the device ?
2. What if I use the `status = "disabled";` option of the DT, will this prevent Linux access to the device ?

Best,
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both option will work because then linux will not try to probe the driver hence no accesses will be made.